# pySpark scalable onehotencoder with binary representation

Tags: python, apache-spark, pyspark, one-hot-encoding

I've been trying to find the best way to onehotencode a large number of categorical columns (e.g. 200+) with an average of 4 categories, and a very large amount of instances. I've found two ways to do this:

1. Using `StringIndexer` + `OneHotEncoder` + `VectorAssembler` + `Pipeline` from `pySpark.MlLib`. I like this approach because I can just chain several of these transformers and get a final onehotencoded vector representation.
2. Appending binary columns to the main dataframe (using `.withColumn`), where each column represents a category from a categorical feature.

Since I'll be modelling (including feature selection and data balancing) using Python packages, I need the OneHotEncoded features to be encoded like **Point 2**. And since `.withColumn` is computationally very expensive, this is not feasible with the resulting amount of columns I have. Is there any way to get a reference to the column names after fitting the Pipeline described in **Point 1**? Or is there any way to make a scalable version of `Point 2` that doesn't involve sequentially appending more columns to the dataframe?

Comment: Without seeing your code, it's hard to tell, but my guts said try to use RDD and build the features like this https://youtu.be/vD3k-moYgmU?t=2263

Comment: Thank you for your suggestion, I will look into it. I was looking at this article https://medium.com/@nutanbhogendrasharma/role-of-onehotencoder-and-pipelines-in-pyspark-ml-feature-part-2-3275767e74f0 for point (1), the problem is that i need to have a separate column for each categorical feature, and not a vector, hence why the `withColumn` approach in (2). The problem is that running `withColumn` for lots of categorical features is not scalable...

Comment: In the video I explained a way to avoid many unnecessary `withColumn`s